# Do mods for games like Skyrim look good on a resume?

Tags: modding

As a lot of people know, Bethesda just came out with their [Creation Kit](http://www.creationkit.com/) for developing mods to Skyrim.

I've been developing for a while, I have a couple of games released including one that's doing well in the App Store. My goal is to get a job at a studio like Bethesda, Bioware, or Valve. Right now my work shows I can do some of the harder parts of a game engine, but I have nothing directly in the RPG field which is where I want to be.

Would building a mod for Skyrim help my resume enough to justify the time it takes to do it, or would my time be better spent making another non-RPG game from scratch? This mod would be a full side game completely separate from the game's world. My usual thought of mods is they are for fun and don't really help the resume as much as more raw projects, but with how open the creation kit is, it seems you can really go a long way in development.

Before I get any *duh* or *subject to opinion* answers, this question is about my lack of knowledge on the perception of notable mods to games. My assumption is there is a general consensus to if mods can be impressive and help a resume which already has some (decent) content for the level of job it's after. Also, I have no intention of starting an RPG from scratch if anyone is crazy enough to offer that as a solution, this is for my resume only.

Lets assume the mod I would make would be impressive for a mod. If that was up for debate, the answer to this might come out a bit gray.

Comment: Considering making a mod is how the creators of Counter Strike got hired, I'd say it can be useful. If you make a mod like CS, you might get hired by a studio like Valve.

Comment: Portal was originally a mod also

Comment: @Noctrine: If by "mod" you mean "total conversion" (why did people stop making that distinction?), then yes, Narbacular Drop was a "mod".

Comment: @NicolBolas, not that it's terribly important, but narbacular drop wasn't developed with source engine. It was developed in Sketcher and when valve acquired the team, they rebuilt it in Source, not a Mod of halflife like counterstrike was though so you're right there

Comment: Drop was built with their own engine (I have the source, in fact) -- I went to school with the original team, and at the time modding wasn't permissible for class projects, which is what Narbacular Drop started out as.

Comment: @JoshPetrie They called their engine "Sketcher Engine" in their design docs, that's where that reference came from, but I'll leave that whole project alone to avoid having it trail on too long as a comment. I made a clone of the portal technology a while back for fun and ran into that

Comment: @JoshPetrie, also the edit on the title is slightly off from my intent. I know it doesn't hurt a resume to have a mod, and it probably looks good. My question was more is it worth it as far as time goes compared to other projects not in the RPG genre.

Comment: I made that edit because I thought the original title was too vague, but asking if something is "worth one's time" is often too subjective, so I tried to strike a balance. Feel free to roll it back or update it yourself though.

Comment: Yea I didn't change it back because I didn't like the original either. Not sure what to put, I guess it doesn't matter since I got some decent answers. Thanks tho

Comment: relevant: http://sloperama.com/advice/lesson51.htm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bethesda specifically asks for experience with their development tools when applying to a position with them. So, if you want a job at Bethesda, successfully completing a mod project is a great step to take to put your foot in the door.

If you don't want to work for Bethesda, a successful mod project still goes a long way to help you. Just think of how popular Skyrim is, if your mod works out that's considerably more eyes on it than many games before it (especially with how Bethesda is promoting modding). If it's awesome, you'll get not only a lot of fans for your own personal work, but even possibly studios looking to bring you in. (To feed off your popularity or just for your talent)

Answer (score 5):

According to this interview http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5ebFjlLptE , doing a mod for Skyrim will help if you want to be hired at Bethesda. For Valve or Bioware, I don't know, although it probably won't hurt.

Also, it depends on the kind of development you do. If you are a core engine programmer, I doubt a mod will show your abilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make a proper mod with a full fleshed out idea, it certainty would help. And, it shows some experience in the rpg genre. However, i would continue to work on your own games.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write game engines, Bethesda's modding kits should be cake.  That's where I started learning to program and it ended up opening up a whole new way of thinking and world to me.  I progressed into Unity, started learning C#, took up Visual Studio and did a bunch of standard object oriented programming, moved into C++ for a brief while, then back to C# and now I'm learning WPF...

Bethesda likes experience in their creation kit/GECK - it's extremely easy to use and script and pretty fun if you like these games - if you want to apply at Bethesda, I would definitely recommend modding - otherwise I'm not sure it would be particularly beneficial anywhere else though having it in your portfolio would help most with showing your view of story flow, level design, and content creativity more than helping bolstering your credit as a quality programmer and/or graphic designer.

Unfortunately, we live in a market that isn't very "quality writing and storytelling" driven otherwise New Vegas would be considered the Magnum Opus of games designed in Bethesda's engine, so I'm not sure most studios would be looking at that first and foremost.  Skyrim had some moments I almost cringed from how bad the writing was...  Some of it was ok..

Comment: Even if you are a competent programmer, using other people's tools or sorting through other people's code isn't always easy. In fact, a lot of the times it can be quite a nightmare. Especially considering the programmers over at Bethesda are not known for their competence. The same could be said for Creation Kit.

Answer (score 0):

As a guy that's been modding many games for the past... 14-18 years, I'll just chip in.

- only a FEW modders ever got paid for their work or somehow got money out of it. IceFrog may or may not be one of them, and I really doubt he got any money out of Valve for DotA2 (if I could actually remember my mail/password for ICQ, i would've asked him now.)
- CounterStrike devs may have got paid, but I doubt that too. UT2k14 in UnrealEngine4 certainly do *not* get paid to make Epic a new game, they just get some developer help from time to time.
- The man that made the skyrim expansion mod, Falskaar did *not* get hired, even though one of the reasons he did everything he featured in the mod *was* to get hired. Thats why he did the voiceacting.
- A few more examples of people that contributed greatly but never got anything out of it: for Warcraft3:TFT Vexorian made a pretty hefty spell system used by all (not all, a big portion of them) maps that feature custom spells that don't behave like original ones. Actually i'll just stop here.

A big thing to note here is - "a mod is *not* protected and copyrighted intellectual property, and anyone is free to remake your mod with different people", which is why I doubt both the DotA author and CS authors got paid for their work.

One of the best ways to actually monetize on your modding work, is to hack the game at some point, and/or ask for donations to keep the servers running after the original multiplayer servers get shutdown.

Just writing this post overflooded me with alot of bad and some really bad memories :/

Comment: " and I really doubt he got any money out of Valve for DotA2 "

This is pretty disgusting if true, seeing as Valve is a multi-billion dollar industry that does nothing more than, like a parasite, take take take from other developers using a fully automated system. But in America, it's ludicrous to request a big corporation to give back to the society in any way which originally propped them up. Paying IceFrog would be bad business. Even a "Thank You" might be too unprofitable to justify. Profit Motive Capitalism FTW!  USA! USA! USA!

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up the fact "a mod is not protected and copyrighted intellectual property, and anyone is free to remake your mod with different people". I'd like to be able to link others to something more concrete to show this to be true. Thank you!

Comment: Some companies ask people to attach a similar text to this to their mods: `"your mod" is not an official Red Hook Studios product or product modification, and Red Hook Studios
Inc. is not responsible in any way for changes or damages that may
result from using the mod. Furthermore, “Darkest Dungeon” and the
Darkest Dungeon logo are trademarks of Red Hook Studios Inc. All content
in the game is Copyright Red Hook Studios Inc. All rights reserved.`

You can get the hint where i borrowed this text from, but the following point remains:

Comment: Just because you had an idea to change/modify/empower someone's product **DOES NOT** give you copyright and/or intelectual property of that "product" mainly because it depends on a already registered, copyrighted intelectual property which is the `base game you modified`. Such actions may even be condemned by the developer/publuisher and even prohibited by the EULA. But I'm no lawyer, and i do have 16 years of "many modding projects" on my LinkedIn page.

Comment: Another, slightly underhanded way of monetizing your mod would be to strike a deal with the developer/publisher and enhance/enforce CD-checks with your modified executable, so that the end-result is: your mod requires the original game to be bought in order to be able to play it. That benefits both sides, and may get you somewhere money-wise but it's actually used as a simple marketing move to boost the sales of a no-longer-selling game. Take a look at `Endless War` mod for XCOM. Or `MW4Free`.

Comment: However, modmakers might get some protection, in a form of bugging the moderator to delete someone's post advertising a mod with very similar (copy/pasted) features as a few other mods on the site, and moderators will usually delete links/posts that contain plagerized work. But like I said - it's not plagiarism, it's you not bothering enough to lock-up and secure your work; once you publish it to the open public it's up for grabs, and anyone is free to rip out your resources and use them in a slightly different context and you have nothing else but to hold a grudge.

Comment: Maybe the person gives is a more adequate role in the game and you learn something new, or buffs it's HP/damage in a cheat-mod fashion or simply copy/pastes it. You know it's your original work and you should be grateful that someone thought so highly of your idea to resort to stealing it rather than making it themselves. It's simply imaginary candy that tastes really sweet. But you can't take them to court over imaginary candy - in the eyes of the law you're both equal consumers of the base product that you bought (or stole) and simply enriched your gaming experience.

Comment: Or you're both in violation of the EULA if the game prohibits you from editing it's base files / resource files which made modding it possible in the first place; but I already addressed that with this comment `"it's someone not bothering enough to lock-up and secure their work"`

The easiest way to look at the situation is like this: Can you ropyright a certain muffin? Can you hold it as your own IP? Can you sue your neighbour for figuring out a very similar or the exact recepy for your special muffin? Muffins are open-domain and everyone can make  them. Because the game you mod is muffin.

Comment: For anyone interested, I added this question here https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/5scvxb/copyright_law_mods_you_true_or_false_a_mod_is_not/

Comment: "But like I said - it's not plagiarism, it's you not bothering enough to lock-up and secure your work; once you publish it to the open public it's up for grabs, and anyone is free to rip out your resources and use them in a slightly different context and you have nothing else but to hold a grudge" I don't think this is true, according to what I've read from VGA on /r/gamedev . He stated that artwork, even when sold, is still owned by the artist unless you have the right paperwork. To claim artwork is public domain just bc it's on the internet "up for grabs" sounds like an assumption...?????

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, just a modder. We all have our presumptions and assumptions but at the end of the day, the judge's word is final. The question you linked on reddit has more to do with artistic licences than modding in general. and laws are different from country to county, state to state.The only way to be really sure (of what you said) is to lock-up your work and remain in control of your work... because as soon as you lose control, things like this happen. Everyone starts having colliding opinios which may not necessarily be true.